# UTF 8 encoding error: should never happen ,java exception

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

In the web application service method, I am trying to parse a xml using VTD-XML.   After reading it from the database, I'm calling the code below.
It's failing to parse and throws an exception:

> UTF 8 encoding error: should never happen

The same code is working in separate class in main method. I am using NetBeans IDE.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebuild_woym_purple_clone1", "root", "root");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
st.executeQuery("select * from revision where name='First');
ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
if(rs.next()){
    String xml = rs.getString(9); 
    System.out.println(xml);
    vg.setDoc(xml.getBytes());
    vg.parse(false); //vtd-xml parser object , throwing exception here
    System.out.println("good");
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but loading a JDBC driver via Class.forName [has been unnecessary for almost ten years](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html).

Comment: ya....I just wrote this to test getBytes() issue...Normally we use conn pools only

Answer (score 3):

The error message indicates that the XML byte array is parsed using UTF-8 encoding, which is to be expected since that is the recommended encoding for XML.

However, when you call [`getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) on a `String`, you get (quoting javadoc):

> Encodes this `String` into a sequence of bytes **using the platform's default charset**, storing the result into a new byte array.

Since it is extremely unlikely that you default charset is UTF-8, you'll get something else, and parsing that as UTF-8 will then fail.

To fix it, use [`getBytes(Charset charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29), as in:

```
vg.setDoc(xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```